# ghost script : Setting overprint mode to 1 not permitted in PDF/A-2, overprint mode not set

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I am trying to perform pdf to pdfa conversation through ghost script with -sDEVICE=pdfwrite.

command is below.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64" "--permit-file-read=srgb.icc" -dNoOutputFonts -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH  -dFastWebView -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB "-sBlendColorProfile=srgb.icc" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 "-sOutputFile=pdfa_output_file.pdf" "PDFA_def.ps" "pdf_input_file.pdf" -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook "pdfSetting.txt"
```

[image]

During the conversion, I am getting this error and it fails to generate a proper pdf/a. Its not showing PDF/A banner in adobe reader.

in PDFA_def.ps file, i have added only ICCProfile (srgb.icc) full path. In settings.txt, i have following changes

```
    [ /PageMode /UseOutlines
  /Page 1
  /PageLayout /SinglePage
  /View [/Fit]
  /DOCVIEW pdfmark
```

I saw this issue has been addressed in so many threads, but those solutions are not helping me.
This issue happens in my pdf where i have some graphical elements.

Am i doing things in wrong way ? Is there anyway to avoid this error ?

I tried with

```
-dOverprint=/enable | /disable | /simulate
```

options, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Note :  when I rerun command with this current output as input to same command, it worked fine. It is becoming compliant in veraPDF.

Comment: You can't set overprint mode in a PDF/A-2 file, it isn't permitted. Trying random command line switches isn't going to help, especially when the problem is Overprint Mode, not Overprint. Your original PDF file obviously sets Overprint mode to 1, the output file does not (hence why it says 'not set'). Creating a PDF/A from that file will succeed because it doesn't have Overprint mode set, but the result may not be correct. You should also use a more up to date version of Ghostscript 9.52 is 3 years old. If a problem persists, open a bug report.